# Modify automatically generated Entity Framework select statement

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

In `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command`, how do I modify the automatically generated `Select` statement so that I can add a `where`?

```
SELECT [o].[UnderlyingSymbol], [o].[Expiration], [o].[IV], [o].[QuoteDatetime]
```

The `Option` `entity` is this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace OptionsAPI.Entities
{
     public class Option
     {
          [Key]
          [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
          [Required]
          public  string UnderlyingSymbol{ get; set; }
          [Required]
          public System.DateTime QuoteDatetime { get; set; }
          [Required]
          public System.DateTime Expiration { get; set; }
          [Required]
          public double IV { get; set; }

     }
}
```

The custom `DbContext` looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using OptionsAPI.Entities;

namespace OptionsAPI.Services
{
     public class OptionsDbContext : DbContext
     {
          public DbSet<Option> Opt_I30 { get; set; }
          public OptionsDbContext(DbContextOptions<OptionsDbContext> options)
               : base(options)
          {
               Database.EnsureCreated();
          }
     }
}
```

The Options `controller` looks like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using OptionsAPI.Services;
using OptionsAPI.Constraints;

namespace OptionsAPI.Controllers
{
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     public class OptionsController : Controller
     {
          private OptionsDbContext _context;
          public OptionsController(OptionsDbContext context)
          {
               _context = context;
          }
          public IActionResult GetOptions()
          {
               return Ok(_context.Opt_I30);
          }
     }
}
```

`My Asp.Net core 3.1` `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using OptionsAPI.Services;

namespace OptionsAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString =
               "Server=xxx.xx.xx.xxx;Integrated Security=false;Trusted_Connection=false;Database=Options;User Id=xxx;Password=xxxxx";
               services.AddDbContext<OptionsDbContext>(o =>
                   o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);    
        }

        //etc...
```

Comment: Primarily in EF, you are querying the objects with _linq_ and that gets translated to a _sql_ query, so if you want to add a where clause you need to add it to the _linq_ query. If you want to build and use plain SQL query, EF Core supports 'FromSQL' . You need to post more details on how you are using it and where exactly you would like to add the _where_ clause.

Comment: I am using it from an ASP.Net Core application.

Comment: I want to add the where clause to the automatically generated SELECT in the post. From the Entity, somewhere somehow it generates this sql statement. I never typed that Select in my code anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code snippet you have posted, this is the place you are querying the entity '`Opt_I30`'

```
public IActionResult GetOptions()
{
    return Ok(_context.Opt_I30);
}
```

Since, you have not supplied any additional filter conditions, the query `_context.Opt_I30` simply translates to `Select * from Opt_I30`. To add additional conditions, you should change your query to something like the below,

```
public IActionResult GetOptions()
{
    return Ok(_context.Opt_I30.Where(o=>o.UnderlyingSymbol=='SYM'));
}
```

The above should generate a SQL query with a where clause.

Note: There are cases when the EF may not generate the where clauses as part of the SQL query, but the condition is applied in-memory.

Comment: EF Core 3 removed the client evaluation "feature".